# Настройка плагина fileman

Tags: javascript, json, ckeditor, zend-framework

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
На сайте использую редактор ckeditor, и подключил файл-менеджер fileman. Настройки этого файл-менеджера лежат в файле conf.json.
вот проблемный участок кода:

```
{
  "FILES_ROOT":  "public/uploads/",
 ...
```

Я тут задаю директорию по умолчанию. Как сделать так, что-бы было вроде такого:

```
{
  "FILES_ROOT":  "public/uploads/{id}",
```

Автоматом заходило в ту папку в зависимости от хеша? К примеру, по такому URL: http://mysite.com/id/1001010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому интересно, то нашел ответ:
в конфиге к примеру задаете:

```
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "myRoxySession"
```

Далее в контроллере уже:

```
$_SESSION["myRoxySession"] = 'public/uploads/ . "$id"'
```